# stax parsing using java if element value blank then assign parsing element to upper element

Tags: java, xml, stax

I am parsing big xml input data using stax parser.

My input xml part will be like below

```
<User>
<LoginName>abcd</LoginName>
<FirstName>abcd</FirstName>
<LastName>kkk</LastName>
<CompanyName>infosys</CompanyName>
<EmailAddress>mmm@gmail.com</EmailAddress>
<CorporateEmailAddress></CorporateEmailAddress>
</User>
```

My stax code is as below

```
private static Message parseMessage(XMLStreamReader xr)
            throws XMLStreamException {
        String userName = null;
        String content = null;
        String email = null;
        String comp = null;

        while (xr.hasNext()) {
            int event = xr.next();
            switch (event) {
                case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT: {
                    String elName = xr.getLocalName();
                    if (LOGIN_NAME.equals(elName)) {
                        userName = xr.getElementText();
                    } else if (CONTENT.equals(elName)) {
                        content = StringUtils.trimToEmpty(xr.getElementText());
                        content = content.replace("\n"," "); 
                    } else if (CORP_EMAIL_ADDRESS.equals(elName)) {
                        email = xr.getElementText();
                        /*if(email.equals(""))
                            email ="unknown";*/

                        conv.emails.add(email);
                    } 
                    else if (COMPANY_NAME.equals(elName)) {
                        comp = xr.getElementText();
                        conv.comps.add(comp);
                        //System.out.println(comp);
                    } 
                    break;
                }
                case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT: {
                    String elName = xr.getLocalName();
                    if (MESSAGE.equals(elName)) {

                        return new Message(userName, content,email);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case XMLStreamConstants.END_DOCUMENT:
                    throw new XMLStreamException("xml not well-formed: <"
                        + MESSAGE + "> tag not closed");
            }


        }
```

here in code if xr.getElementText(email) is null as  doesnot have any value. SO in this case I want to use  tag value

So how to assign again xr.elementText to loginvalue? only when cor-email is null

Please help

Comment: Watch for an appropriate `END_ELEMENT` (`"User".equals(elName)`?) (an use the "fall-back-value" there instead of trying to "assign" it to an attribute of some parser instance).